# GoDaddy Socket.IO net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript

I followed the socketio/docs and it is was perfectly work in localhost port 8000, but when I do it on my webhosting (Godaddy) my server is running but my client can't connect to my server;

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var socket = io('http://serverip:3000');

socket.on('alert', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

socket.emit('click', "hello server?");
```

**server.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket){


socket.emit('alert', 'hello from server');

socket.on('click', function(data){
console.log(data);

});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log("1 client disconnected");
});
});
```

NOTE: I run the server.js using Bitvise Terminal (node server.js)

Comment: Are you sure your hosting supports Node.js? If so, check other ports. Is it still throwing an error?

Comment: yes i install node.js in my host

Comment: Have you resolved this issue or found a work around? I have a very similar situation. I use PuTTY to connect to my server as well as used it to download node.js, npm, express, socket and whatever else is normal to have. My code works for local host but as soon as I attempt to bring it over to my godaddy hosted website, nothing get's past socket. My 'server.js' code does not notice whenever someone opens up the page with the socket variable.